# Do PS4 games still get a performance upgrade on PS5 if run from external storage?

Tags: ps4, performance, backwards-compatibility, ps5

The PlayStation 5 (PS5) has the option to run PlayStation 4 (PS4) games from an external USB drive to save space on the main drive for more intensive PS5 games, which can only be run from the internal storage itself.

Several PS4 games I own have received PS5 upgrade patches (without being a full-scale “PS5 version”), like Ghost of Tsushima, which upgrades the frame rate, etc.

If I attempt to run these games from an external drive, will those improvements apply or will the extra transfer overhead make it revert to lower settings?

Answer (score 2):

You will still gain the benefits of the increased CPU and GPU improvement such as increased FPS, but you'll be missing out on the increased hard drive speed of the PS5.

Comment: I suspect that you are right but it would be good if you can add a source for this information.